# Can this javascript code be cleaned up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

The code is working just fine now, but is a bit sloppy and long. I'm not as proficient in js as I would like to be.

Javascript

```
    $("#IDArea1").click(function () {
        $('#indicator1').toggleClass("icon-caret-up icon-caret-down");
        $('#indicator2').removeClass("icon-caret-up");
        $('#indicator2').addClass("icon-caret-down");
        $('#indicator3').removeClass("icon-caret-up");
        $('#indicator3').addClass("icon-caret-down");
    });
    $("#IDArea2").click(function () {
        $('#indicator2').toggleClass("icon-caret-up icon-caret-down");
        $('#indicator1').removeClass("icon-caret-up");
        $('#indicator1').addClass("icon-caret-down");
        $('#indicator3').removeClass("icon-caret-up");
        $('#indicator3').addClass("icon-caret-down");
    });
    $("#IDArea3").click(function () {
        $('#indicator3').toggleClass("icon-caret-up icon-caret-down");
        $('#indicator2').removeClass("icon-caret-up");
        $('#indicator2').addClass("icon-caret-down");
        $('#indicator1').removeClass("icon-caret-up");
        $('#indicator1').addClass("icon-caret-down");
    });
```

DOM Structure

```
<div id="IDArea1">
    <i class="icon-caret-up"></i>
</div>
...
<div id="IDArea2">
    <i class="icon-caret-down"></i>
</div>
...
<div id="IDArea3">
    <i class="icon-caret-down"></i>
</div>
```

Basically, the first area (IDArea1) is open by default. Then, depending on which heading you click, will toggle the clicked heading to the opposite icon and force the others to be "icon-caret-down". So the structure of each function is the same and I have a feeling there is a cleaner way to execute this code, I just can't find a solution.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you combine some CSS and a simple class with an attached onclick event, sure, this can be cleaned up easily.

Comment: Why don't just create a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename *f*() to something else that makes more sense to your domain:

```
var f = function(indicatorClicked, remainingIndicators) {
    $(indicatorClicked).toggleClass("icon-caret-up icon-caret-down");
    $.each(remainingIndicators, function(index, indicator) {
        $(indicator).removeClass("icon-caret-up").addClass("icon-caret-down");
    });
}

$("#IDArea1").click(function () { f('#indicator1', ['#indicator2', '#indicator3']) });
$("#IDArea2").click(function () { f('#indicator2', ['#indicator1', '#indicator3']) });
$("#IDArea3").click(function () { f('#indicator3', ['#indicator1', '#indicator2']) });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can clean up your code.

You can create a function like this:

```
function iconCaret(el1, el2, el3, el4, el5) {
    $(el1).toggleClass("icon-caret-up icon-caret-down");
    $(el2).removeClass("icon-caret-up");
    $(el3).addClass("icon-caret-down");
    $(el4).removeClass("icon-caret-up");
    $(el4).addClass("icon-caret-down");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something you could try. Haven't tested it so it may contain typos. `[id=^'IDArea']` selects elements with `id` starting with "IDArea".

```
$("[id=^'IDArea']").click(doStuff);

function doStuff(){
    var num=$("[id=^'IDArea']").eq(this);
    $('#indicator'+num).toggleClass("icon-caret-up icon-caret-down");
    $("[id=^'indicator']").not('#indicator'+num).removeClass("icon-caret-up").addClass("icon-caret-down");
}
```